# Spinning up Redis server in sentinel mode using testcontainer for integration tests in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, testcontainers, redis-sentinel

I recently learned of `testcontainers`, so I wanted to use it for an integration test cases, for a Spring Boot application.

I have tried many combinations to achieve this, but it isn't working / starting. For example, the below is the latest code I tried:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.Network;
import org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.Wait;

public class RedisSentinelIntegrationTest {

    private static final int REDIS_MASTER_PORT = 6379;
    private static final int REDIS_SENTINEL_PORT_1 = 26379;
    private static final int REDIS_SENTINEL_PORT_2 = 26380;

    @Test
    void testRedisSentinel() {
        Network network = Network.newNetwork();

        // Redis Master
        GenericContainer<?> redisMaster = new GenericContainer<>("redis:6.0.12")
                .withExposedPorts(REDIS_MASTER_PORT)
                .withNetwork(network)
                .waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort());

        redisMaster.start();

        // Redis Sentinel 1
        GenericContainer<?> redisSentinel1 = new GenericContainer<>("redis:6.0.12")
                .withExposedPorts(REDIS_SENTINEL_PORT_1)
                .withNetwork(network)
                .withCommand("redis-server", "--sentinel", "yes", "--sentinel-announce-ip", "redis-sentinel-1", "--sentinel-announce-port", String.valueOf(REDIS_SENTINEL_PORT_1))
                .waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort());

        redisSentinel1.start();

        // Redis Sentinel 2
        GenericContainer<?> redisSentinel2 = new GenericContainer<>("redis:6.0.12")
                .withExposedPorts(REDIS_SENTINEL_PORT_2)
                .withNetwork(network)
                .withCommand("redis-server", "--sentinel", "yes", "--sentinel-announce-ip", "redis-sentinel-2", "--sentinel-announce-port", String.valueOf(REDIS_SENTINEL_PORT_2))
                .waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort());

        redisSentinel2.start();

        String sentinelUrl1 = "redis://" + redisSentinel1.getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + redisSentinel1.getMappedPort(REDIS_SENTINEL_PORT_1);

        String sentinelUrl2 = "redis://" + redisSentinel2.getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + redisSentinel2.getMappedPort(REDIS_SENTINEL_PORT_2);

     // .. do something

       

        // Stop the containers
        redisMaster.stop();
        redisSentinel1.stop();
        redisSentinel2.stop();
    }
}
```

But to my dismay it never works; isn't testcontainers supposed to ease life? I tried their official website, but again they haven't given any such example.

How can I use Redis testcontainers to run in sentinel mode and successfully run it? What issues might I have in the set up?

Comment: Isn't it necessary to pass a `sentinel.conf` file as an argument to `redis-server --sentinel`? Can you start Redis with those arguments, manually (so not from Java but from the CLI or with Docker)?